Should opinion-based questions be moved to Discussions instead of being closed?
Given that discussions are made for more open-ended and subjective posts, should posts that don't fit SO be moved there?
Pros:

It would populate discussions with more questions.
The asker and anyone searching for the question would get an answer (potentially) instead of a closed question.
Moderation workload would be slightly reduced as one would not have to check to reopen the question if the user edits it after closure.

Cons:

Some legitimate questions that have a definite and objective answer, but only need some rewording, might be "lost" to discussions. See also this.
Low reputation/new users might be encouraged to post on Discussions instead of improving their posts/posting on "regular SO".

An opinion-based question would still need flagging. Instead of closing due to "needing improvements", the flag option could be moved like this:

Should this be implemented, the user should be informed as to why the post in question was moved.

Ehh, the discussion space is a disaster... The OP would better off going to a place that actually has engagement from users that isn't just "Flag post as Spam/Rude or Abusive/Not suitable for Discussions".

How about we just delete questions seeking discussions instead of supporting a horrible hostile idea like discussions? We don’t need to populate discussions, with anything, we need to simply not support them

Maybe an automatic transfer of the question to Reddit?

@SecurityHound While discussions is by no means perfect I'd like to give it a chance at least. There is some potential in a less rigorous environment to talk about programming.

Wouldn't moving them to discussions be the same thing as closing them? If anything it'd even be worse, as they now cant be improved by the community or reopened.

@A-Tech - Discussions is a result of Stack Exchange not listening to the community. I want no part of it. I have seen what discussions are, I have nothing positive to say about discussions, so i won’t say it.

It's interesting to examine this question and answer from nearly a decade ago. Today we have Staging Ground and Discussions, which can be seen as instances of "The Beginner's Place" and "Crap Overflow" mentioned in the answer. I've been participating in SG, time will tell if it's a success. After peeking in a few times at Discussions I could see it was hopeless and have avoided it.

I'd rather support @Dharman idea. As one of the "unfortunate" users dealing with Discussions on a regular basis, I'd say getting rid of it altogether is the most sound and reasonable FR of all.

IMO? ... yes. But I'm hugely pessimistic and think that discussions exists to draw in traffic that the Q&A site is not good for. It's not there to be actually useful, it exists to give people a place to put slice of time content that immediately becomes pointless and never looked at again.

Some legitimate questions that have a definite and objective answer, but only need some rewording, might be "lost" to discussions. If it can be edited to have an objective answer, it shouldn't have been closed on the first place. Editing a question into shape when possible is better than downvoting or closing.

Until (if) Discussions is made into an actual viable product, I can only state that this is not worth it.
At the moment the Discussions feature has next to no activity from active members of the community on the main site; almost all the content is from (very) low rep users. The majority of posts don't get responses, and many responses I do see are about as low quality as the original post.
The vast majority of posts (cannot provide citation due to see later in the post) that I visit I end up flagging as Spam/Rude or Abusive/Not suitable for Discussions. I think I've flagged seven such posts today, which are all now deleted, which means that 70% of the posts posted today (at the time of writing) were removed.
Before we start pushing stuff that isn't on-topic for Main into Discussions, Discussions needs to be complete, that means it needs:

Good onboarding, there is literally none at the moment.
A reputation requirement (so many posts are by 1 rep users and aren't on-topic there or on main); I wonder if on-boarding would help mitigate that..?
Better Flagging (Why can I still not see my history?)
Mod messages for Discussions Mods (they can't tell me why they decline a flag, or if it was the wrong flag, or anything).
Community Edits
An active community (hahaha, good joke!)
Down votes (because much of the content is terrible, and it's being hidden).
...
Profit (quite literally this time)

Discussions is almost certainly a forgotten feature at this point; Stack Overflow "tried" (barely) and it failed. It should just be switched off at this stage.
If the post the user has made is well written, VTC the post and if you want to, point them to an active community you know of that is off-site; be that Reddit, Yahoo Answers, or a specific community for that technology. They'll have a better experience somewhere else.

"Down votes (because much of the content is terrible, and it's being hidden)." alternatively no votes. Either the community can decide what is interesting/good/worthwhile/whatever "voting" should mean themselves, or they don't and it acts like a forum. Having just upvotes is entirely meaningless and accomplishes nothing. Well, except SE trying to discourage users less from posting there. A decision of dubious value, given that I agree that a lot of things posted there shouldn't have been.

When I looked at Discussions on Saturday morning the last 14 posts where all spam.

I'm not against no votes as well, @VLAZ, but you're right that only upvotes is just stupid.
